# tf_prefix for Fixed Frame in RViz

Tags: ros, rviz, tf-prefix

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using ROS Groovy and have just implemented using tf_prefix for the /tf joint states. However, while RViz correctly interprets the transform data, it does not apply the `tf_prefix` argument to the Fixed Frame. Is there any way to do this? I've had a search but nothing jumps out at me.

Kind Regards
Bart

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/174107/tf_prefix-for-fixed-frame-in-rviz/) by [bjem85](https://answers.ros.org/users/18596/bjem85/) on ROS Answers with karma: 163 on 2014-06-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The fixed frame is just a parameter, you can set it with the full value of the frame_id including the prefix if you want.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bjem85](https://answers.ros.org/users/18596/bjem85/) on 2014-06-26**:
That is exactly what I'm trying to avoid. I don't wish to hard code the transform prefix. However, at this time it's still possible to set the frame while RViz is running, so it's annoying but not fatal.